# core data chatting applicate fetch a batch of messages ordered by date

Tags: iphone, ios, sql, database, core-data

I am making a chatting application. The messages are stored using core data with the following format:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate * datetime;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * text;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * type;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * sent;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * read;
@property (nonatomic, retain) DBRoom *room;
@property (nonatomic, retain) DBUser *sender;
```

Now I need to retrieve messages of a chatting room. My original implementation is simply:

```
self.messages = [Helper mutableArrayWithSet:self.currentRoom.messages sortKey:@"datetime" ascending:NO];
```

Where I use a helper method `mutableArrayWithSet`

```
+ (NSMutableArray *)mutableArrayWithSet:(NSSet *)set sortKey:(NSString *)key ascending:(BOOL)ascending {
    NSSortDescriptor *descriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:key ascending:ascending];
    NSArray *array = [set sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:descriptor]];
    return array.mutableCopy;
}
```

Then I just keep the top 10 messages and remove the rest. When user scroll up to get history messages, I fetch again and keep 20 messages.

The problem is, if there are many messages, it may affect the performance. I think the problem is `self.currentRoom.messages`. It's convenience but it's not efficient.

Is there a way to fetch messages batch by batch, like "select a batch of messages (from 20th to 30th) ordered by datetime", or "select the 3rd batch of messages with batch size of 10, ordered by datetime"

EDIT:

I just read through the documentation and found this:

"You can use this feature to restrict the working set of data in your application. In combination with fetchLimit, you can create a subrange of an arbitrary result set.
"

Comment: Use [`NSFetchedResultsController`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to fetch the messages and display them in a `UITableViewCell`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `NSFetchRequest` `- (void)setFetchBatchSize:(NSUInteger)bsize`. I'm not sure it works on relationships, so you might have to change your `NSFetchRequest` to fetch with `Message` entity directly, instead of using `self.currentRoom.messages`.

Comment: you mean fetch the top 30 instead of fetch 20th-30th?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. [fetchBatchSize](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSFetchRequest_Class/NSFetchRequest.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFetchRequest/fetchBatchSize) - here's a full explanation of how fetching in batches works.

Comment: isn't the batch size just a hint for the system to speed up batch by batch?

Comment: No, you can set [com.apple.CoreData.SQLDebug](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/coredata/Articles/cdPerformance.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003468-SW13) to print SQL queries to `stderr` and you'll see that they're performed in batches.

Comment: I have edited the question. It seems I need to use batch size and limit to get a subrange.